# Latency using Parse.com from european Server

Tags: performance, parse-platform, latency

I create a simple hello world function using the Parse.com service. (cf: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started-simple)

When I call it with curl from a hosted server on europe, i obtain 400ms to 800ms response time.

Is that a normal latency for this service ?
Does someone using this service from somewhere else could try this function and tell me your latency ?

I have no response from Parse about it.

Answer (score 1):

I write this in January, 2014. Parse.com is rapidly growing and expanding their platform. I cannot say how long this information will be correct or how long my observations will remain relevant.

That said...

I think this latency is very typical. I am in Seattle, USA. Here are some informal benchmarks:

Getting a single object via the REST API has pretty consistent RTT of 800ms

- GET https://api.parse.comapi.parse.com/1/classes/Element/xE5sZCQd6D
- Response: Status=200, Round trip time=0.846
  ICMP is blocked, but just knocking on the door takes 400-800 ms, depending on the day.
- GET https://api.parse.comapi.parse.com/1
- Status=404, Round trip time=0.579

Parse.com is in Amazon's data center in Northern Virginia. I used Ookla's Speedtest to estimate my latency to that area. Reaching the Richmond Business Center server (75.103.15.244) in Ashburn gives me a ping time of 95ms. A server in D.C. gave me a ping time of 97 ms. Two hundred milliseconds of Internet overhead is not the problem.

Be aware that using Cloud Founds will also increase your perceived latency. The more queries or save operations a Cloud Function performs, the longer response time. Cloud Functions with one or two queries or save operations have an RTT between 1 and 3 seconds. Cloud Functions with multiple queries and save operations have an RTT between 3 and 10 seconds.